# "æ" vs "ə" in narration

Tags: pronunciation

Movie quotes from subzin.com:

> 00:34:12 I'm sorry, Dwight.
>
> 00:34:20 An atom bomb goes off between my leg.
>
> 00:34:24 A freight train **barrows** into my jaw.
>
> 00:34:30 I've taken a beating before but never like this.
>
> *Sin City 2: A dame to kill for*

The violent scene happens when the narrator is heavily punched across the face.

I suspect it's **burrows** rather than **barrows**, but the question here is not just about a possible typo. The narrator is an American. Normally, He would pronounce it as /bərəu/ instead of /bʌrəu/. After a little search, I find **barrow** is rarely used as a verb. And it doesn't fit with the context semantically.

I was wondering why it's pronounced as /bærəu/ if it's indeed a typo. I have difficulty distinguishing the two vowels sometimes.

Comment: "barrels" is another possible transcription.

Comment: @Jasper You nailed it!!

Comment: In some US dialects, the first vowel in "furrows", "burrows", "hurry", "furry", "slurry", "blurry", etc is the same as  the vowel in "stir" and "her". In other dialects, it's closer to schwa.

Comment: I  can find *burrow* with a kit or nurse vowel but not with a schwa in the first syllable ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top comment is correct, the transcription should say *barrels*. This verb is most commonly used for things like trains and trucks (e.g. "Barreling down the highway"). It is movement with a great deal of momentum. *Burrowing* is not something that trains usually do and doesn't make sense in this context. *Barrow* is rarely used as a verb, as you said.